# Jquery .append() not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, append, appendchild

I am trying to execute below code. It's working fine with chrome and firefox but giving me issue with IE 11.

Error message in IE is:
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error

Code is:

```
$("div#formFields").append(
                        $("<label/>").text(formField['Data'][i]['field_label']),
                        $("<input/>", {
                            type: text,
                            id: 'selectTest',
                            name: 'selectTest',
                            required: "true",
                        }),
                    );

<div id="formFields" >
</div>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the last comma inside append . See my code below

```html
<body  id="banner">
<div id="formFields" ></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    
    $("#formFields").append(
                    $("<label/>").text("Texts"),
                    $("<input/>", {
                        type: "Texts",
                        id: 'selectTest',
                        name: 'selectTest',
                        required: "true",
                    })//Remove comma from here, 
                    //Comma added at the end will cause syntax error in IE
                );
    
    
    });

    </script>
</body>
```